# How can I programmatically determine the current default codepage of Windows?

Tags: winapi, character-encoding

I have to convert the encoding of a string output of a VB6 application to a specific encoding.

The problem is, I don't know the encoding of the string, because of that:

> According to the VB6 documentation when accessing certain API functions the internal Unicode strings are converted to ANSI strings using the *default codepage* of Windows.

Because of that, the encoding of the string output can be different on different systems, but I have to know it to perform the conversion.

How can I read the default codepage using the Win32 API or - if there's no other way - by reading the registry?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It could be even more succinct by using [GetACP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318070(VS.85).aspx) - the Win32 API call for returning the default code page! (Default code page is often called "ANSI")

```
int nCodePage = GetACP();
```

Also many API calls (such as [`MultiByteToWideChar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072(VS.85).aspx)) accept the constant value `CP_ACP` (zero) which always [means "use the system code page"](http://www.siao2.com/2005/01/06/347834.aspx). So you may not actually need to know the current code page, depending on what you want to do with it.

Comment: Thanks to whoever suggested the edit to mention "ANSI" and improve code formatting slightly. Good idea, I've edited it accordingly myself.

Comment: This usage of ANSI is quite nonsensical. The Windows code pages are often referred to as ANSI code pages, because they were intended to become standard; they never did though. Using then 'ANSI' to only refer to the default is highly confusing and I've never seen it used like this.

Answer (score 2):

[GetSystemDefaultLCID()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd318121(VS.85).aspx) gives you the system locale.

If the LCID is not enough and you truly need the codepage, use this code:

```
  TCHAR szCodePage[10];
  int cch= GetLocaleInfo(
    GetSystemDefaultLCID(), // or any LCID you may be interested in
    LOCALE_IDEFAULTANSICODEPAGE, 
    szCodePage, 
    countof(szCodePage));

  nCodePage= cch>0 ? _ttoi(szCodePage) : 0;
```

Comment: Or more succinctly, as in my answer: `int nCodePage=GetACP();` :) It's quite long-winded to get the name of the code page and then get the code page as a string and then convert to an integer

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me, thanks, but can be written more succinctly as:

```
UINT nCodePage = CP_ACP;
const int cch = ::GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT,
     LOCALE_RETURN_NUMBER|LOCALE_IDEFAULTANSICODEPAGE,
     (LPTSTR)&nCodePage, sizeof(nCodePage) / sizeof(_TCHAR) );
```

Comment: Or even more succinct, as in my answer: `int nCodePage=GetACP();` :) It's a bit long-winded to get the *name* of the code page and then look up the identifier code from the name