# How to get windows xp gui default code page?

Tags: c++, character-encoding, windows-xp

The thing is that on non-english versions of XP code pages for console and gui apps differ, for example if I on my Polish version write in console:

```
echo zażółć gęślą jaźń > somefile.txt
```

The content of that file is:

```
zaľ˘† g©lĄ ja«ä
```

This isn't happening if I put that into cmd file. That is this text with polish letters. But if I create a file or directory that is named using non English only chars, then no matter if it's run from cmd or from finger the effect is always gibberish.

So my question is how to get this second code page that rest of windows is running with. In my case this CP is 1250 - but how to get this number from c++ ?

`GetConsoleCP()` and `GetConsoleOutputCP()` both return 852 (which is correct) and `GetThreadLocale()` gives 1045.

If I try to `chcp 1045` it gives "wrong code page".

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909913/how-can-i-programmatically-determine-the-current-default-codepage-of-windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage\ACP` - this registry key stores the ANSI code page number (it should be 1250 in your case) and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage\OEMCP` stores OEM code page.

Oh, and there are [GetACP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318070%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [GetOEMCP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318114%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions.